# generating two classes from one table in database using eclipse reverse engineering

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I tried to make hibernate reverse engineering of a simple table called Student in SQL Server database that contains an identifier as primary key and the name of a student.
Whenever I make eclipse reverse engineering I always get two classes; Student class and StudentId class. The Student class contains just an object of StudentId class. And StudentId contains the identifier and the name.

what is the solution for that?

Comment: Did you accidentally add both columns to the primary key of the table? That would make the primary key a compound key, requiring a class for representing the two values together, and leaving no other fields in the main class. --- Oh, solution: Remove name column from primary key.

Comment: no i just make the identifier column in database as primary key. Thanks a lot for this suggestion

Comment: Show the DDL for your table. Use the "Script as Create" in SQL Studio, and edit question to include it there.